# How to Do ES 6 Arrow for Event Handlers with Parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I needed to make a event handler I was doing it like

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
```

I have since learned that this is not the best way to do it as the handler gets created each time.

I since learned you can do something like

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  console.log('Event', e);
}
```

what makes sense to me but it's when you need to pass some other pramaters that I get bit confused

```
handleClick = (param) => (e) => { 
  console.log('Event', e);
  console.log('Parameter', param);
}
```

I don't really get the 2 arrows I thought it would be like

```
handleClick = (param, event) => { 
  console.log('Event', e);
  console.log('Parameter', param);
}
```

Also what happens if I have more than 1 would it be

```
   handleClick = (param, param2, param3) => (e) => { 
      console.log('Event', e);
      console.log('Parameter', param);
    }
```

Comment: Read about currying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying

Comment: Its a function that returns a function. When you do `onClick={this.handleClick(param1)}` it returns `onClick={(e) => { ... }}` but with your params in scope for the function to use

Comment: As a note, if you curry the function it will also be created in every render. You need to use the function reference and find a way to get the parameters there.